# Freeglut window: No title Bar

Tags: c++, opengl

I created a window with freeglut and it's weird that there's no title bar of the window.I am not allowed to upload a pic for my reputation is low.

Has anyone met this kind of problem ?The main function is as following code.

```
glutInit(&argc,argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA|GLUT_DEPTH|GL_DOUBLE);
glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
glutCreateWindow("particle test window");

glutDisplayFunc(DrawGLScene);
glutReshapeFunc(ReSizeGLScene);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
glutIdleFunc(idlefunc);

InitGL();
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "title block"? The title bar? You can upload images to imgur.com or similar and add a link.

Comment: Yes, the title bar. Have you met this problem?

Comment: I never had this problem. However I see another problem in your code: You passed GL_DOUBLE to glutInitDisplayMode, while it should be GLUT_DOUBLE. It could be that GLUT misinterprets GL_DOUBLE as a flag that makes it hide the titlebar, but I'm guessing here.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's just the reason causing the problem.